# Git submodule visible till the point I permit

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repo which contains some reusable code. Say the name of that repo is **reusable-rpo**. Now there is a client who has created a private repo and granted me with read-write access. That repo is meant for creating a product. Let's call it **product-repo**. Now I want to use **reusable-repo** as a submodule in **product-repo**. But when I will finish the development of the product the client should be able to have all the code which is in the **prodcut-repo** including the submodule code. After that I will continue to do more commits in **reusable-repo** but I already don't want the client to access that code from submodule too. Can I achieve this? Or should I use other mechanism instead of submodule?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to manage this would be with a fork of `reusable-repo`.

`product-repo` would use the *fork* of `reusable-repo` as a submodule.

You manage `reusable-repo` as you see fit, and update the fork as long as `product-repo` is in development.

But once the development of `product-repo` is finished, you freeze (no longer update) that `reusable-repo` fork.
`product-repo` will keep the reference to that forked repo, without seeing any new commit from the original `reusable-repo`.